# Cannot Autowire Spring Batch Itemreader,writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to create a batch configuration class but i couldnt inject this fields idk why class annotations :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Component
public class SpringBatchConfig {

and here is code 

     @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                   StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                   ItemReader<Object> personItemReader,
                   ItemProcessor<Object, Person> itemProcessor,
                   ItemWriter<Object> personItemWriter
                   ){

        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-File-Load")
                .chunk(100)
                .reader(personItemReader)
                .writer(personItemWriter)
                .build();
        Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL-Load")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step)
                .build();

    return job;
```

and this is the full error :

```
Parameter 2 of method job in com.emir.batchjobtest.config.SpringBatchConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: please post stack trace of error

Comment: So _do_ you have an `ItemReader` in your configuration?

Comment: you're likely missing a `@Component` (or `@Service`) annotation on your `ItemReader` class. If there is just one implementation.

Comment: Thank you i forgot the add component annotation to my itemwriter and processor class now it works <3

Comment: this is a configuration class hence adding component here is not right.